# how to handle address dimension with 75M locations

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I am creating an address dimension for a Snowflake Schema Data Warehouse.  I have 75M locations on a source that I want to convert to said schema.  I know how to handle Zip->City->County->State dimensions, but if I add street addresses to the location dimension I would have an equal number dimension rows as fact rows.

What I need to know, is where should the street addresses go (123 anywhere St.)?  Should it go in the fact table? How do I handle street addresses?

Thanks.

Comment: no.  it's 75M locations.  it's a real estate app I'm building for a client.  We have 75M addresses.

Comment: sales information on each record.  when a house gets sold, that's what's captured in fact.

Comment: Sounds like a typical dimension - houses are your products and the address is one of the attributes. Do you need to load all the houses? Is there a transaction for every address in the database?

Comment: into the warehouse, yes.  Not necessarily to the datamarts.  The house's salesdate is the type 2 change indicator for that particular location.  there's about 20 metadata statistics that gets collected with each house.  some static (ie. num of bathrooms), some on type 2 change (sale date and price).

Comment: to that end, I might have a fact with the same house multiple times.  Either way, it's alot, because we'll hold mostly one sale per house.

Comment: Shouldn't the sale date and the price go into the fact table? From my point of view these are attributes of the transaction, not the house. How are you planning to calculate things like total value of transactions per month? This should be possible without joining the houses dimension?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now.  The question was the address dimension.  Most examples are city, state, zip.  There's no references on street addresses and numbers.  That's why I was asking here.  I have 75M locations.  90% of them unique.  the other 10% are new transactions based on saledate and price. Each with an independent street addresses.  It's the address component I was working on.  It looks like you are saying to leave street address and number in address_dim regardless.

Comment: The decision to use a snowflake schema is another this I don't understand, but I admit I don't know all the details. However, let's approach it from a different angle - why are you asking? What problem are you facing? Why does 75M rows in a dimension worry you?

Comment: I guess it spawns the idea of the join.  It would be 75M(fact) to 70M (dim) (the 90%).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91325/discussion-between-arcee123-and-marek-grzenkowicz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The street address itself should go in a Fact. If it's a Real Estate app I'd imagine there'd be some kind of "Sale Contract Fact" or "Rental Contract Fact" or something similar - the street address would be an attribute of that fact.

In your instance the instance of the address is definitely tied to a single transaction. As you said, the same street address could appear multiple times, but it would be on different Sales Contracts and thus different Fact instances.

Other elements of the address (zipcode, city, state etc) would be dimensionalised as it makes sense to group them for classification.